# function naming conflicts

Tags: r, conflict, naming, data.table, lubridate

What are some good patterns for development with packages that define the same function? In my case, `lubridate` and `data.table` both define `wday`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `::`, it helps to specify which package to use:

```
lubridate::wday
function (x, label = FALSE, abbr = TRUE) 
UseMethod("wday")
<environment: namespace:lubridate>

data.table::wday
function (x) 
as.POSIXlt(x)$wday + 1L
<environment: namespace:data.table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the namespace mechanism for your packages.  See the R Extensions manual.