# Two functions with the same name in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Masked functions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842120/masked-functions-in-r)
>   [R: Masked Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879377/r-masked-functions)
>   [function naming conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490359/function-naming-conflicts)

If I have two packages: A and B. Say there is function named `funfun` in A and there is function named  `funfun` in B too. When I load A and B, how do I use the first `funfun`?

```
require(A)
require(B)
```

If I want to use `funfun` in A, how do I write this?

Comment: Some near duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842120/masked-functions-in-r, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879377/r-masked-functions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337716/how-do-i-use-functions-in-one-r-package-masked-by-another-package

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can explictily refer to a package and function combination like this:

```
A::funfun
B::funfun
```

---

In unusual circumstances, you may have to refer to functions that are not exported in the namespace, in which case you need to use:

```
A:::funfun
B:::funfun
```

(But this would be unusual, and since non-exported functions do not form part of the package API, these functions could change without warning in subsequent releases of a package.)

Comment: If the function is exported you may only need to use `::`.

Comment: +1 Strictly speaking, `:::` allows access to functions that are not exported in the package namespace - this isn't something that most users should have to do. Since I think it's more appropriate to use `::` I have edited the answer.